# How to create a css animated slide-up notification message?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to create a css animated slide-up notification/confirmation message. I'm using react js and the message should slide up from the bottom of the page, stay there for a few seconds and then slide down out of sight. I'm running into problems where the message just goes way down and seems to be out of sight, but if you scroll down you can see it at the bottom of the page. It may have something to do with the css display properties.

*edit*

This is the notification component I'm using. I got it from the web somewhere and have made a couple of mods to it:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Container = styled.div`
    background-color: ${props => props.backgroundColor};
    color: ${props => props.color};
    padding: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: ${props => props.shift}px;
    left: ${props => props.left};
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 999;
    transition: bottom 1.0s ease;
    border-radius: 5px;
`;

export default function Notification({ msg, showNotification, set_showNotification, type = 'info', left = '35%', duration = 5000 }) {  // 'type' can also be 'error'
    const distance = 500;
    const [shift, set_shift] = useState(-distance);
    const [showing, set_showing] = useState(false);
    const [timeout, set_timeout] = useState(-1);

    const color = type === 'error' ? 'white' : 'black';
    const backgroundColor = type === 'error' ? 'darkred' : 'whitesmoke';

    useEffect(() => {
        return function cleanup() {
            if (timeout !== -1) {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            }
        }
    }, [timeout]);

    if (showNotification && !showing) {
        set_shift(distance);
        set_showNotification(false);
        set_showing(true);

        let t = setTimeout(() => {
            set_shift(-distance);
            set_showing(false);
        }, duration);

        set_timeout(t);
    }

    return (
        <Container shift={shift} color={color} backgroundColor={backgroundColor} left={left}>{msg}</Container>
    );
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: I just edited my original post. There you can see my code.

Answer (score -2):

use google.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations

pair this with some `setTimeout()` functions to remove the class after the animation has ended and you're good to go

Comment: Sliding divs from the left, right or top seems to be easier and I might just go that route but since I am currently sliding up from the bottom (and back down out of sight, or trying), I'm interested in getting that to work. Sometimes I can scroll down and see the div and that is the problem. It seems promising to wrap the div with another div with position set to fixed.